# Getting only last sent message from forwarded email message using regex in php

Tags: php, regex, email

I need to parse email content of the forwarded message. I need to classify the email messages into two categories:

1. Primary Content (The most recent message of the email)
2. Secondary content (All other messages of the email)

Here is my email content:

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: Khalil Ahmad <otheremail@gmail.com>
Date: Fri, May 12, 2017 at 10:27 AM
Subject: Re: Discussion
To: Hammad Rasheed <myemail@gmail.com>


ok no problem

On Fri, May 12, 2017 at 10:26 AM, Hammad Rasheed <myemail@gmail.com>
wrote:

> Great.
>
> I just want to check how this reply thing works
>
> On Fri, May 12, 2017 at 10:23 AM, Khalil Ahmad <otheremail@gmail.com> wrote:
>
>> yup fine
>>
>> On Fri, May 12, 2017 at 10:23 AM, Hammad Rasheed <myemail@gmail.com>
>> wrote:
>>
>>> Hi,
>>>
>>> How are you doing?
>>>
>>
>>
>
>
> --
> ---------------------------------------------------------------
> Hammad Rasheed
> Ph: 0332-123456
> myemail@gmail.com <myemail@gmail.com>
> Connect with me on Linkedin:
> http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxx
>

-- 
---------------------------------------------------------------
Hammad Rasheed
Ph: 0332-12345852
myemail@gmail.com <myemail@gmail.com>
Connect with me on Linkedin:
http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxx

--001a114b102aa2bdb7054f4d014a
```

I was able to extract all the forwarded messages using the following regex:

```
preg_match_all('~^>.*~m', $body, $secondary);
```

Now I need to the return message (last one) that was sent i.e "ok no problem" message that does not start with ">" character. But I am unable to make regex for that.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Something like this, but it can be further enhanced - https://ideone.com/mDYSiv.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew This did for me. 
You can add that as answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I suggest is matching any text in between the first line that starts with `To:` followed with something containing an email-like string inside `<...>` and up to the first line starting with `On` followed with space, some letters, spaces and digits (date/time). This can be enhanced futher, but the idea will be the same:

```
if (preg_match('~^To:[^<>]*\s+<[^>@]+@[^><]+>\s*(.*?)\ROn [A-Za-z]+, [A-Za-z]+ \d+, \d+ at \d+:\d+~ms', $email, $m)) {
    echo $m[1];
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/mDYSiv)

Note the modifiers: `/ms`. The `m` modifier makes sure `^` matches the start of the line, and `s` makes sure `.` matches line terminators.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of line
- `To:` - a literal substring
- `[^<>]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` and `>` (add `\n\r` to stay on the same line if necessary)
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (replace with `\h+` to stay on the same line matching only horizontal whitespace)
- `<[^>@]+@[^><]+>` - an email-like substring within `<...>`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars as few as possible (since `*?` is lazy and matches as few chars as possible that are necessary for a valid match
- `\R` - a line break
- `On [A-Za-z]+, [A-Za-z]+ \d+, \d+ at \d+:\d+` - a literal substring `On`, space, and a datetime like pattern (`[A-Za-z]+` matches 1+ letters and `\d+`  matches 1+ digits).

Comment: I added explanations, with some hints on what can be improved if it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for

```
(?P<primary>(?:(?!^>).*\R))+
(?P<secondary>(?:^>.*\R)+)
```

In `verbose` and `multiline` mode, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/9gbLlV/1/).